# Java connect to Amazon Redshift

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc, amazon-redshift, intellij-plugin

I am having trying to connect to Amazon Redshift Database with my Java code. I found a code snippet on AWS website that should work. However I am running into problems with implementing the JDBC driver. 
This is the website and the code from the website: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-in-code.html

```
package connection;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Docs {
//Redshift driver: "jdbc:redshift://x.y.us-west- 
2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev";
//or "jdbc:postgresql://x.y.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev";
static final String dbURL = "***jdbc cluster connection string ****"; 
static final String MasterUsername = "***master user name***";
static final String MasterUserPassword = "***master user password***";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
       //Dynamically load driver at runtime.
       //Redshift JDBC 4.1 driver: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver
       //Redshift JDBC 4 driver: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc4.Driver
       Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver");

       //Open a connection and define properties.
       System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
       Properties props = new Properties();

       //Uncomment the following line if using a keystore.
       //props.setProperty("ssl", "true");  
       props.setProperty("user", MasterUsername);
       props.setProperty("password", MasterUserPassword);
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, props);

       //Try a simple query.
       System.out.println("Listing system tables...");
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       String sql;
       sql = "select * from information_schema.tables;";
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

       //Get the data from the result set.
       while(rs.next()){
          //Retrieve two columns.
          String catalog = rs.getString("table_catalog");
          String name = rs.getString("table_name");

          //Display values.
          System.out.print("Catalog: " + catalog);
          System.out.println(", Name: " + name);
       }
       rs.close();
       stmt.close();
       conn.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
       //For convenience, handle all errors here.
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
       //Finally block to close resources.
       try{
          if(stmt!=null)
             stmt.close();
       }catch(Exception ex){
       }// nothing we can do
       try{
          if(conn!=null)
             conn.close();
       }catch(Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    System.out.println("Finished connectivity test.");
 }
```

}

I got my connection credentials, but I get a following error.

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc4.Driver**

which is caused by this line:

```
Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver");
```

I don't have this driver implemented anywhere so the error makes sense. The problem is that IntelliJ IDEA has a plugin for this (Database Navigator) that doesn't work as expected and I couldn't get any help on their forums.

Is there any other to include the JDBC driver so the code can work with it (in IntelliJ)?

**EDIT:**

After adding the JAR as an external library, my project looks like this:

[image: Current project]

However, when I run the code, I get the same error.

Comment: Us this to connect Db  
`DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver());
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", MasterUsername);
properties.setProperty("password", MasterUserPassword);
this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.READ_SHIFT_URL, properties);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the Amazon Redshift JDBC driver like this :

- Click on File
- Project Structure (CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S on Windows/Linux, ⌘ + ; on Mac OS X)
- click on modules on your left Modules
- click on Dependencies
- '+' → JARs

Comment: This works. I see the driver in the External Libraries list. However I still get the same error. The path to the driver seems to be correct. Do I need to import the external library in the code?

Comment: @JanHorčička Did you right this line : `import java.sql.*;` ? Make sure to replace the `*` by what you specially need

Comment: I didn't write it, it was in the sample code from the website. I am not sure what I need since I am a total newbie.

Comment: How would importing `ojdbc6.jar` (which is the Oracle JDBC driver) fix a problem of connecting to redshift?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well you're right. I wrote without thinking too much. But I edited my answer. My bad

Comment: I edited the question and added screenshot from IntelliJ. Does this help you locate the issue?

Comment: @JanHorčička You need to add the **jar** file as a dependency, you seem to have unzipped the jar, and then - incorrectly - referenced the `com` folder as library. If you go that root, then you should add its parent folder as library, not the `com` folder.

Answer (score 0):

- Dowload the Amazon Redshift JDBC driver from below URL.

  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#download-jdbc-driver
- Add the downloaded Jar to your classpath.

It will work.

You could follow steps as suggested by @Corentin to perform step #2.

Comment: I followed the steps by @Corentin. When I run the code, I get the same error (see updated question).

Comment: change `Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver");` to `Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");` Also make sure to download the jar `https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.15.1025/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.15.1025.jar' and add it to classpath, I have tested myself it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following Maven/Gradle dependency or  download the Amazon Redshift JDBC driver from the following URL

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42/2.1.0.24

Run the program by passing the correct dbURL and credentials. It will work